# Fell topology vs. convergence of matrix coefficients

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

My question is partially inspired by the following discussion:
[Topology on the Unitary Dual](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134312/topology-on-the-unitary-dual)
Let me remind/explain how the Fell topology is defined (at least I recall the definition which I saw): let $G$ be a locally compact group. One first consider the set $Prim(G)$ of so called *primitive ideals* (those being a kernel of the irreducible representation): for $S \subset Prim(G)$ one defines $\overline{S}=\{I \in Prim(G): \bigcap S \subset I\}$. It is not too hard to show that this operation satisfies all properties of "being a closure" therefore it defines the topology on $Prim(G)$ where closed sets $S$ are those, for which $S=\overline{S}$. There is also natural mapping from the space $\hat{G}$ of all equivalence classes of irreducible representations $[\pi] \mapsto \ker \pi$ and one can define the topology on $\hat{G}$ as the weakest topology for which this map is continuous. This topology is called the *Fell topology*. According to the cited discussion, it should be true that convergence in this topology is equivalent to convergence of all matrix coefficients. However, since we deal with *classes* of representation, one should be careful how this convergence is defined: my guess would be the following. Let $([\pi_j])_j$ be a net in $\hat{G}$: we say that $[\pi_j] \to [\pi]$ where:
for each $\varepsilon >0$, compact $K \subset G$ and each $\xi_0,\eta_0 \in \mathcal{H}_{\pi}$ such that $\xi_0 \perp \eta_0$ there exists $j$ and $\xi_j,\eta_j \in \mathcal{H}_{\pi_j}$ such that for all $x \in K$:
$$|\langle \pi_j(x) \xi_j,\eta_j \rangle - \langle \pi(x) \xi_0,\eta_0 \rangle|<\varepsilon.$$
So my question is the following:

> **Is the convergence in the Fell topology equivalent to the convergence of matrix coefficients defined above?**

EDIT: I should have been more precise: there is a one-to-one correspondence between nondegenerate representations of the so called *full* $C^*$-algebra of the group $C^*(G)$ and unitary group representations (this correspondence preserves the notion of irreducibility). All primitive ideal are therefore in this $C^*$-algebra. In particular my question also makes sense in the general context of $C^*$-algebras and I'm also interested in the answer for such a question.
EDIT 2: I corrected the obvious mistake pointed out in the answer.

Comment: Can you precise your definition of a primitive ideals? It is an ideal of what ring exactly? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your inequality you need to evaluate the $\pi$'s somewhere! 
Unless I am mistaken unpacking [Fell (1962), Theorem 2.2 and Remark following](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=150241), $[\pi_j]\to[\pi]$ means that for every choice of an $\varepsilon>0$, a compact set $K\subset G$, an integer $n$, and vectors $u_1,\dots,u_n\in\mathscr H_\pi$, there exists a $j_0$ such that when $j\succcurlyeq j_0$, $\mathscr H_{\pi_j}$ contains $v_1,\dots,v_n$ such that 
$$
\left|\langle u_i,\pi(g)u_i\rangle-\langle v_i,\pi_j(g)v_i\rangle\right|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and all $g\in K$. In short, positive-definite functions associated with $\pi$ are *uniform-on-compacta* limits of positive-definite functions associated with the $\pi_j$.
(See also [Dixmier (1977)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=458185), 3.4.10 for $\mathrm C^*$-algebras and 18.1.5 for groups.)

Comment: Thank you, in fact I think it is enough to use results from another Fell's paper, namely _The dual spaces of $C^*$-algebras_ which is cited in paper which you mention. I will look closer on it. And obviously you are right about my mistake, sorry!

Comment: @truebaran Right, Theorem 1.5 of that (1960) paper already characterized the topology in terms of its closure operation. But, so far as I can tell, the careful neighborhood basis characterization (which allows an easy description of net convergence) first appears in the 1962 paper.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the book of Wallach Real reductive groups II, on Chap XIII you will find a neat answer to your question. best jorge

Comment: Hello Jorge! Welcome to MO!